# Need a regex for a string that must have letters but can't have purely numbers and cant have special chars

Tags: regex

Need a regex for string such that:

1. Can have letters, numbers
2. ignore special characters like: < > { } [ ] # ~ ^/\"
3. Can't have purely numbers
4. Max size is 20 chars

Valid answers
a) "hello world 123 -"
b) "123 hello - world"
c) "- hello 123 world"

Invalid answers
a) "123456"
b) "123456 "
c) "abc>>>"
c) "abc123>>>"
d) ">>>>"
The closest i've come up with is:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9 '\-!\£\$:;%&amp;\*\(\)_=\+,.\?@\n\r\t]{1,20}$
```

But point 3 of "Can't have purely numbers" becomes invalid.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
^(?![0-9]+$)(?!.*?[<>{}\[\]#~^\/"]).{1,20}$

^ - Line start
(?![0-9]+$) - Not just numbers
(?!.*?[<>{}\[\]#~^\/"]) - Doesn't have these special characters
.{1,20} - 1 to 20 characters
$ - Line end
```

Comment: think there's a problem with your 2nd line - (?!.*?[<>{}\[\]#~^\/"])

Comment: What kid of problem with that?

Comment: \/" (that bit towards the end)

Comment: That is to escape `/` since most of regex use `/` delimiters.

Comment: Hey Anu bai, I think I've sorted it - i've changed your line too. Cheers - middle bit should be (?!.*?[<>{}\[\]#~^/\\""])

Comment: Where are you from? Delhi?

Comment: My home-town is Lucknow but have spent many years working in Delhi.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41184/discussion-between-user532104-and-anubhava)